Why is do/while looping infinitely after condition was expected to have been met?
Goal: Delay execution of function by at least 1 second.
The problem: Instead of a minimum 1 second delay the do {} while loops forever.
The steps:

After 1 second timer is set to timerLength.
If the fetch() takes more than 1 second no further delay is added.
If the fetch() takes less than 1 second further execution will be delayed by up to 1 second by do / while loop.



let timer = 0;
const timerLength = 1000;
    
setTimeout( () => {
    timer = timerLength;
}, timerLength); 
    
// fetch request and other code here... 
    
do {  } while(timer !== timerLength); // no code inside do while
    
// Code after this point is expected to run after a minimum delay of 1 second after setTimeout.




do {  } while(timer !== timerLength); will never allow the timeout callback to execute, because javascript is essentially single threaded

You must be correct because it loops forever.  But logically is my code correctly thought out?  Or am I missing something else obvious besides the nature of JS?

But logically is my code correctly thought out? no, because of the point I just made - the javascript event loop should make it clearer

You're not thinking asynchronously.  You have a comment labelled // Fetch and other code here. What's going on in there? Why are you trying to create a delay loop? Create a callback that the Fetch and other code can call when it's done, and not worry about the delay. It does look like an XY problem to me.

@JaromandaX , this is from your link.  Is this what you were refering to?  "This offers some nice properties when reasoning about your program, including the fact that whenever a function runs, it cannot be preempted and will run entirely before any other code runs (and can modify data the function manipulates)."

@TangentiallyPerpendicular , the reason for the delay is to keep an animation on the screen for a minimum of 1 second but not necessarily more.  I thought this would be a simple way to accomplish that.  But nope.

Then wrap up the code that is supposed to execute after a second into a function and call that from your setTimeout() instead of the short function you have there. If you need to wait for the Fetch and other code to complete, as well then you need to look at promises so that you call your new function only when the timeout and the fetch resolve, but that's a whole new block of code.

Yep the Fetch and some other code has to finish executing first.  I'll have to get it done with a Promise.

Logic Analogy:  start kettle boiling...  sit on sofa while tea not in hand...    kettle boils, but you don't have tea in your hand, so you can't go get the tea to have it in your hand to stop waiting to go get the tea

The steps you outlined will not run in that order because setTimeout() (and fetch() although you removed that using comment syntax) is asynchronous.
Asynchronous functions are not run on the Call Stack but are removed and handled differently. Their results are placed on a Task Queue leaving the Call Stack free to run synchronous code.
The Event Loop keeps checking from time to time for a perfect time to take the first callback from the Task Queue and execute it but since you kept the Event Loop busy with an infinite loop, it will never be free to do these other things.
do {  } while(timer !== timerLength);
/* The above runs forever because
timer !== timerLength will never become false
Since setTimeout hasn’t run. */
Use an async function to run asynchronous code and await their result.
Take a deep dive into the Javascript Event Loop [MDN] and how to write asynchronous code [MDN].

If you need to wait for two or more operations to complete before continuing, you need to use promises.
In your case, create a promise for your timeout, and use the promise returned by fetch. Pass these to promises to a Promise.all() so that Promise.all() only resolves when both your original promises resolve.
E.g.
<script>
    "use strict";

    // set timeout promise. Resolves after 1000 milliseconds
    const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
        }, 1000);
    });

    // Fetch something. May take longer than a second. Resolves when data is returned.
    const promise2 = fetch("http://some/url/somewhere.php");

    // Wait until all promises in the array resolve
    Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(()=>{alert ("All Done.");});
</script>

